# What word is used to replace a redacted name?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

If a name of an military officer is redacted for security reasons, how can I replace his name with an adjective and the word 'officer' without too much hubbub?

Say the original sentence is "The meeting was led by Lieutenant Smith and his men." Can I say, "The meeting was led by an **unnamed/redacted** officer and his men"? If not, how should I say it?

Comment: Unless you want to make sure the audience knows the name is purposely withheld, I'd just say "one of the officers and his men".

Comment: Yes, I want to indicate his name was purposely redacted. By the way, names aren't normally redacted for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a letter instead of the last name, such as in this passage:

> These passports must be countersigned, and, strangely enough, my friend's required the sign-manual of Lieutenant X., whose office was in the lower part of the city, while mine must be signed by Lieutenant Y., who made his head-quarters some distance farther up town.
>   <sub>[A Rebel's Recollections](https://docsouth.unc.edu/fpn/eggleston/eggleston.html?highlight=WyJHZW9yZ2UgRWR3YXJkIFBpY2tldHQiXQ==)</sub>

Using letters like this allows the reader to keep track of who is being referred to even when you have multiple such unnamed individuals (in this example multiple unknown lieutenants). Lettering usually is x, y, z or a, b, c... using letters as needed. It’s also perfectly ok to use when it’s just one unnamed person.

To make it clear these aren’t real initials you can use a clause that says something like “whose name(s) we cannot release for security reasons”

Comment: Another example of this approach is https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/279160/0029_x.pdf ie the Northern Ireland Bloody Sunday Inquiry report. It lists the redacted names at start as follows *Soldiers given ciphers by this inquiry: A, B, [...]*

Comment: If I needed to mention that person a number of times, I might say, "General A accomplished his mission over a period of two weeks." But since I'm only mentioning him once, I was looking for a way to say what was done while indicating his name was redacted in a document.

Answer (score 1):

Different organizations and governments will use different methods.

For instance, here's what the Federal Court of Australia says in its ["Guide to Redacting Documents in Electronic Form"](http://www.fedcourt.gov.au/online-services/preparing-documents-for-the-court/guide-to-redacting-documents-in-electronic-form):

> Text or numbers that need redacting should be replaced with the word redacted in square brackets [Redacted]. For example, “the funds were transferred to the applicant’s nominated bank account BSB [Redacted] Account number [Redacted]”. To maintain the formatting or structure of the document the word and square brackets ‘[Redacted]’ can be repeated, for example, ‘[Redacted] [Redacted] [Redacted]’.

Based purely on this Australian guideline, your sentence would become:

> The meeting was led by [Redacted] [Redacted] and his men.

On the other hand, I've seen news stations present redacted documents to viewers in which the words or phrases are simply blacked out or otherwise hidden.

I imagine you would need to refer to the "redaction guide" of whatever agency you work for to determine what its own guidelines are.

---

In speech (I wasn't sure if when you said *how should I say it*, you were talking about speaking about something redacted), unless you are actually reading a redacted document, I imagine that you refer to the person or situation in exactly the same way as if information about them or it isn't known in the first place.

In other words:

> "The meeting was led by somebody and his men."

That doesn't name the person or his rank.

I don't think there would be any reason to say *unnamed* or *redacted* as an adjective every time you would otherwise say something. (Nor would you do that if paraphrasing something in writing.)

Perhaps you could start off, or finish, by mentioning something along the lines of:

> This [is/was] all the information I [can/could] provide you, due to certain information being redacted.

Comment: I could say, "The mission, led by an officer (whose name is redacted), lasted for two weeks."

Comment: @BillStreifer Indeed you could. But if you're narrating something, it would get tiring quickly to keep saying something like that with every instance of redaction.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Luckily, I only need to mention him once. What he did is discussed in a paragraph or more.

Comment: @BillStreifer In that case, initially mentioning that his name is redacted as you suggest (assuming that his gender is not also redacted) is fine.

Comment: From the context, he could only have been male.